# Write status messages to a textbox asynchronously?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I recently started programming in WinForms using C#. I have a requirement where I need to search a set of folders and the sub-folders and display the status information to a textbox as I do the search like -

Looking up folder "C:\Windows"...
Found 8 files...
Copying file 1 of 8 to "D:\Temp"...

I have a method which does all the searching and stuff. I don't know how to display the status messages (like above) to a textbox periodically. Currently, the form waits for the method to be complete, and displays the messages all at once. I want them to be displayed one by one as the method progresses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a BackgroundWorkerThread and the ReportStatus function.  That way your UI will be responsive while the search takes place.

Answer (score 2):

To properly solve this your searching function will need to be running on a background thread.  If the searching occurs on the UI thread it will block updates to the display preventing a periodic status message from being displayed.

The easiest way to do this in a WinForms application is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  It has a minimum of support for running a task on a background and returning progress information to the UI thread.  Additionally there are a lot of tutorials available online to get you started with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run the method that performs searches on a separate thread (if you're not doing so already). It's quite easy using the [async delegate features in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(VS.71).aspx).

You can then write to the text box from the worker thread using [Control.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) - you must do this because access to UI control sis affinitized to the single UI thread.

You can also create a [background worker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and use the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method to notify the UI of updates. There's a [fairly complete example](http://dotnetkicks.com/winforms/BackgroundWorker_complete_example) of this approach available here that you can download and examine.